# check 10 digit mobile number in string using php

Tags: php

I want to check 10 digit number in following strings using php

```
$str1 = "when an unknown 8109100000 remaining essentially unchanged.";
$str2 = "when an unknown remaining essentially unchanged.";
```

when find 10 digit number then return true

Answer (score 1):

You can use **preg_match**

Code

```
    $str1 = "when an unknown 8109100000 remaining essentially unchanged.";
    $str2 = "when an unknown remaining essentially unchanged.";
    $pattern = "/\b\d{10}\b/";
    $isNum = preg_match($pattern,$str1, $match); //return 1 $str2 return 0.
    if($isNum){
     //Do something
    }
    else{
    //Aww.... No number in string.
    }
echo $match[0]; //return matched number.
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/0p2hb)

Read more about [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)
[Regex](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#chars)

Comment: This pattern returns true for 10+ digits, not only 10 digits. https://3v4l.org/nYRbD

Comment: @Andreas \b boundary added.

Answer (score 1):

In order to only match exact 10 digits you need to combine the `{}` with the `\b` in the regex pattern.
`{}` specifies the number of digits and `\b` means match complete words.

In this example only the last string should return true/1.

```
$str = ["when an unknown 810910000011 remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "when an unknown remaining essentially unchanged.",
        "when an unknown 8109100000 remaining essentially unchanged."];

Foreach($str as $s){
    Echo preg_match("/\b\d{10}\b/", $s) . "\n";
}
```

And it outputs

```
0
0
1
```

As expected

https://3v4l.org/QesPA